# How to pass chosen value from drop down list to the database table

Tags: php, html, mysql, post

I have a drop-down list and I want to pass the chosen values such as 'ID', 'input1' to the database. The user chooses one row from the drop-down list and when he clicks submit all values should go to the database table. How to achieve this with POST method?

```
 <form action="demo2.php" method="post" />
                                <p>
    <select name="command">
    <?php 
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT ID,input1, input2, input3, input4, input5 FROM demo");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo "<option value=\"owner1\">" . $row['ID'] . '.' . $row['input1'] . ' - ' . $row['input2'] . "</option>";}
    ?>
```

Part of my demo2.php. This is just an example of what I want to achieve.

```
$value9 = $_POST[$row['ID']];
$sql2 ="INSERT INTO table ID VALUES ('$value9')";
```

Comment: Just a tip, do not pass data like that into the database, you open up for injections, look into PDO or MySQLI

Comment: Select list behave in two ways. If there is a value specified <option value'..'> then this value is sent to the server. If there is no value attribute then the information between the option tags is sent to the server. In you case change the owner1 to $row['ID']

Answer (score 0):

First remove / in the opeing of the form,

```
<form action="demo2.php" method="post">
  <p>
    <select name="command">
      <?php $sql = mysql_query("SELECT ID,input1, input2, input3, input4, input5 FROM demo"); ?>
      <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)): ?>
        <?php echo "<option value=\"owner1\">" . $row['ID'] . '.' . $row['input1'] . ' - ' . $row['input2'] . "</option>"; ?>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
    </select>
  </p>
  <button type="submit" name="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and the add submit button

Answer (score 0):

In order to get and pass the value from the options you need to call the name of the `select` tag.

```
$value9 = $_POST['command'];
$sql2 ="INSERT INTO table ID VALUES ('$value9')";
```

something like that. This might be helpful.

Comment: I know this, but you see my select name is one and there are three variables, so if I take it like $value9 = $_POST['command'] it would take entire row with all three variables and then put them in the ONE column of the table? Lets say my one row of the drop down list has  variables input1 input2 input3 taken from the other table, but when I click submit I want to pass input1 to one table and input2 to the other. I couldn't use the same $value9.

Comment: I see so you better use 'join' table here